# Strings after special characters

Tags: php

```
$string = "ce_content youtube_bMnXEbm-JGw first"
```

I want to get the strings after `youtube_`: `bMnXEbm-JGw`

$string can contain also other content like:

```
$string = "image youtube_bMnXEbm$wdwJGw first highlight"
```

Comment: OK, good for you. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "image youtube_bMnXEbm\$wdwJGw first highlight";
```

First you want to use a regular expression to match all of those strings. The parentheses on the second part mean that that piece of the string are captured sepearately.

```
preg_match_all('/youtube\_([^\s]+)/', $string, $matches);
```

Since you may have more than one match, you have to loop through them all. This also checks if there were any matches.

```
if (isset($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[1])) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $match){
        echo $match;   
    }

}

//output = bMnXEbm$wdwJGw
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string in following way with the neat built-in PHP function `explode()`, no need of hungry regular expressions engine, example:

```
<?php 
$string = "image youtube_bMnXEbm$wdwJGw first highlight"
$pieces = explode("youtube_", $string ); 
foreach ($pieces as $key=>$value) {    
   echo $key.$value; 
}
```

See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: Then how would he get just the `bMnXEbm$wdwJGw` part?